# Setting up v3 in app billing with Google Play Store

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-play

I have set up in a project in app billing v3 following the steps of this tutorials:

http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html
http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

The problem I have is that when I request the details of a product doing the following:

**Requesting the products details**

```
ArrayList<String> appIdList = new ArrayList<String>();
appIdList.add("tn38g");
appIdList.add("f4zn");
appIdList.add("kjecm");
appIdList.add("1j16a");
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, appIdList, mQueryFinishedListener);
```

**Receiving the call back**

```
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mQueryFinishedListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inv) {

        if(result.isFailure()){
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Shop Query Failiure!");              

        } else {

            List<SkuDetails> listOfItems = inv.getSkuList();
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfItems.size(); i++) {
                SkuDetails details = listOfItems.get(i);
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "details.getTitle() = " + details.getTitle());
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "details.getPrice() = " + details.getPrice());
            } 
            SkuDetails details = inv.getSkuDetails(mCustomerHasDocuments.getIssue().getAppstoreIdentifier());

            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "details = " + details);

            if(details != null){
                price = details.getPrice();
            }
            populateButtons();
        }
    }
};
```

Even if the product with the same product ID are in the google play developer console, **the call back always return an inventory without any product details.**

Anyone with the same problem? What can be wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

These are the logs:

```
07-09 19:31:22.962: D/PublicationDetailView(28874): success at Shop Setup!

07-09 19:31:23.742: D/(28874): QueryInventoryFinishedListener
07-09 19:31:23.742: D/(28874): result.getMessage = Inventory refresh successful. (response: 0:OK)
07-09 19:31:23.742: D/(28874): result.getResponse = 0
07-09 19:31:23.742: D/(28874): result.isSuccess = true
07-09 19:31:23.742: D/(28874): listOfItems.size() = 0
07-09 19:31:23.742: D/(28874): details = null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a real credit card. However, you can always refund your test purchases!

Note that you'll have to make the purchases from a test account that's separate from your developer account, since Google Checkout doesn't allow an account to buy from itself.